# How to design Azure NotificationHub for sending notifications without tag and more than 10k users

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I am using azure notificationhub to send push notifications. I can send push notifications to all my subscribers. But if I want to send messages to a group with 10k users messages are not going all of them. Tried with for loop within a web app.
I can't test this too much because these are real individuals. Which way do you recommend me to desing it?

1- Insert a record in redis for every user and a message. Then trigger a web call to function app and in that function app send push notification one by one and delete after sending.

2- Send a record in Queue Storage for every user and a message. Trigger a function app with queue and delete one by one.

3- Send a record for every message only and retrieve users in the function app and send notification one by one.

I am open to other recommendations

Comment: May I know why want to send notifications without a tag?  If the count of the user is out of limit. Based on my understanding you could divided them to more than one group. And send the notifications to the groups.

Comment: Hi Tom, tags would be very good but we want to send a push to a group of calculated users sometimes. This calculation occurs in our server. I did not design the project but took over it and I don't have past experience with notificationhub.

Comment: If you have a huge number of user, it is not recommended that send the message to user one by one. As you mentioned that you if want to calculate the user in the service side, it seems that you could use the ways you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the batch send API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/direct-batch-send. It allows you to send a notification to a set of device IDs (1,000 at a time). It still requires some looping (because of the 1,000 device limit) but that's the recommended solution.